# "RequestError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate" error after updating certificate of API server

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, node-modules

I have this website (let's call it a.com) which is on AWS. It is done using NodeJs backend and view front end. It is calling another system API (let's call it b.com) for the DATA from some other URL.

This site was working fine. We updated SSL certificate of site b.com and now site a.com is not able to receive data from site b.com.

When I checked the error log on AWS, this is the error I found:

```
RequestError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at new RequestError (/var/app/current/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
at Request.plumbing.callback (/var/app/current/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/var/app/current/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
at self.callback (/var/app/current/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

What can be the issue?

Can I do any settings on my NodeJs server to load data from b.com?

The site is working fine on my localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, there are problems validating the SSL certificate of `b.com`.
I see you're using `request` library, so as a workaround you could pass `strictSSL: false` in options:

```
{  
    url: 'https://b.com',
    method: 'GET',
    ...
    strictSSL: false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Necessary warning: Turning off all SSL certificate validation is dangerous. A [MiTM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (e.g. a sniffer/spoofer on your local network) can read or replace any of your data if you do it. Don't do it if you can help it.

- A better solution: export or otherwise set [`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) environment variable for your process, and point it to a working root certificate CAs file.
- Configuration equivalent: `npm config set cafile "<path to certificate file>"`
- A worse <strike>solution</strike> workaround: export or otherwise set [`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value) environment variable.
- Configuration equivalent: `npm config set strict-ssl false`. This may not work for installation scripts that ignore the configuration.